# Multiple events in a single click

Tags: java, events, actionlistener

I have a program which searches and gives you a list of objects in a frame (Frame1). I added a JInternalFrame object creation in the menu so you can open one of this under the label saves and store the objects. You can open more than one of this saves frames. On the object list (in Frame1) there is a popup menu (menu1) so that you can choose the option save. When done, another popup menu becomes visible (menu2) showing the different saves frames you have created (Frame2, Frame3,...). To do this I add a for loop each time you click on the save button on the first popup menu (menu1) since you can add saves frames (Frame4,...) after opening the search frame (Frame1). The issue arrises that each time the event for the mouseListener happens in the second popup menu (menu2) it gets accumulated. For example, the first save I do saves as it should. The second save saves the object two times. The third saves the object three times and so on.

I guess this is happening since the event is called upon multiple times. If this is the issue, is there a way to clear the event after beeing called? En the event parameter string you can see that when being called multiple times, the time (when) is the same.

```
private void popSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    savesCreados = frmMenuP.getSaves(); //# of JFrames(int)
    xy=getXY();
    menuSaves = frmMenuP.getMenuSaves(); //JMenuItems
    int selectedRowIndex = tabResults.getSelectedRow();
    nombre = tabResults.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex,0).toString(); //Object to save
    for(int i=0;i<savesCreados;i++){
        JPopupMenu2.add(menuSaves.get(i));
        System.out.println(i);
        menuSaves.get(i).addActionListener(new 
java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            popSaveMenu(evt);
        }
    });
    }
    JPopupMenu2.show(tabResults,xy[0],xy[1]);
    }



private void popSaveMenu(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    listaSaves = frmMenuP.getListaSaves();  //JFrames
    System.out.println(evt.paramString()); 
    for(int i=0;i<=frmMenuP.getSaves();i++){
        if(evt.getActionCommand().contains(Integer.toString(i))){
            System.out.println("Guardar " + i);

            listaSaves.get(i-1).saveAt(nombre);
        }
    }
    }
```

0
1
ACTION_PERFORMED,cmd=Save1,when=1570501305410,modifiers=Button1
Guardar 1

0
1
ACTION_PERFORMED,cmd=Save1,when=1570501315585,modifiers=Button1
Guardar 1
ACTION_PERFORMED,cmd=Save1,when=1570501315585,modifiers=Button1
Guardar 1

0
1
ACTION_PERFORMED,cmd=Save1,when=1570501378104,modifiers=Button1
Guardar 1
ACTION_PERFORMED,cmd=Save1,when=1570501378104,modifiers=Button1
Guardar 1
ACTION_PERFORMED,cmd=Save1,when=1570501378104,modifiers=Button1
Guardar 1